# FlatList Giving Warning: Maximum update depth exceeded

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I'm getting the **Warning**:

> Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component calls setState inside useEffect, but useEffect either doesn't have a dependency array, or one of the dependencies changes on every render.

Without even using useEffect. I think the problem might be that when I update a state by selecting RenList re-renders cause an infinite re-renderization but I don't know how to fix it or how to be sure that the problem is that.

```js
    const data = [{
        id: "aa",
        fullName: "aa",
        timeStamp: "aa",
        recentText: "aa",
        avatarUrl: "aa"
      }, {
        id: "bb",
        fullName: "bb",
        timeStamp: "bb",
        recentText: "bb",
        avatarUrl: "bb"
      }, {
        id: "cc",
        fullName: "cc",
        timeStamp: "cc",
        recentText: "cc",
        avatarUrl: "cc"
      }, {
        id: "dd",
        fullName: "dd",
        timeStamp: "dd",
        recentText: "dd",
        avatarUrl: "dd"
      }, {
        id: "ee",
        fullName: "ee",
        timeStamp: "ee",
        recentText: "ee",
        avatarUrl: "ee"
      }
    ];
    
    const RenList = () => {
    
      return (
    
        <Box>
            <Heading fontSize="xl" p="4" pb="3">
              Inbox
            </Heading>
            <FlatList data={data} renderItem={({
            item
          }) => <Box borderBottomWidth="1" _dark={{
            borderColor: "gray.600"
          }} borderColor="coolGray.200" pl="4" pr="5" py="2">
                  <HStack space={3} justifyContent="space-between">
                    <Avatar size="48px" source={{
                uri: item.avatarUrl
              }} />
                    <VStack>
                      <Text _dark={{
                  color: "warmGray.50"
                }} color="coolGray.800" bold>
                        {item.fullName}
                      </Text>
                      <Text color="coolGray.600" _dark={{
                  color: "warmGray.200"
                }}>
                        {item.recentText}
                      </Text>
                    </VStack>
                    <Spacer />
                    <Text fontSize="xs" _dark={{
                color: "warmGray.50"
              }} color="coolGray.800" alignSelf="flex-start">
                      {item.timeStamp}
                    </Text>
                  </HStack>
                </Box>} keyExtractor={item => item.id} />
          </Box>
    
      );
    };
    
    const RenTot = () => {
      const [firstSel, setfirstSel] = useState('');
      const [secSel, setsecSel] = useState('');
      return (
        <NativeBaseProvider>
        <Box>
          <VStack>
            <Center>
              <FormControl isRequired>
              <Select
                    selectedValue={firstSel}
                    minWidth="200"
                    accessibilityLabel="Elegi categoria"
                    placeholder="Elegi categoria"
                    _selectedItem={{
                      bg: "teal.600",
                      endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
                    }}
                    mt={1}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => setfirstSel(itemValue) }
                  >
                    <Select.Item label="Num1" value="Num1" />
                    <Select.Item label="Num2" value="Num2" />
                    <Select.Item label="Num3" value="Num3" />
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Center>
    
            <Center>
              <FormControl isRequired>
              <Select
                    selectedValue={secSel}
                    minWidth="200"
                    accessibilityLabel="Elegi categoria"
                    placeholder="Elegi categoria"
                    _selectedItem={{
                      bg: "teal.600",
                      endIcon: <CheckIcon size="5" />,
                    }}
                    mt={1}
                    onValueChange={(itemValue) => setsecSel(itemValue) }
                  >
                    <Select.Item label="Num1" value="Num1" />
                    <Select.Item label="Num2" value="Num2" />
                    <Select.Item label="Num3" value="Num3" />
                </Select>
              </FormControl>
            </Center>
          </VStack>
        </Box>
          <RenList/>
        </NativeBaseProvider>
        );
    };
    
    export default RenTot;
```

Comment: I suspect the issue lies in a parent component where this component `<RenTot />` is being rendered. This component works fine in isolation.

Comment: @ParasDaryanani It's being rendered in a normal screen using Navigation. I find it weird though because that shouldn't break it.